# Unable to list all the posts on blog page

Tags: wordpress

> I am trying to get all the posts from my wordpress site to one single page. after implementing the custom theme first i created the page named "blog". In settings->reading i set the post page to blog. I created some posts. but instead of showing these posts my blog page show index page. I have tried same procedure on default activated theme then it is working fine. please let me know what can be the issue for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a page named blog, then the template to produce the content of the page should be called page-blog.php (in your theme folder).